# Getting Error while building war of spring boot application but code is working and running,even tried adding fasterxml dependency

Tags: spring-boot

---

### Test set: com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.412 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Comment: post your application class

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your project after adding the `fasterxml` library. And make sure that it is downloaded by whatever the build tool you are using after the build is complete. Check the External Libraries. It should contain the `fasterxml`. If not, check why it's not being downloaded or add it manually to the classpath